# VueJS radio button (b-form-radio) remains unchecked

Tags: vue.js, radio-button, bootstrap-vue, checked

I have a collapsible dropdown with collapsible groups inside, each group having a list of radio buttons, grouped in a b-form-radio-group.
When I open the page, I populate all the fields with data and I need a radio button to be check, if some conditions are met.
I tried to use :checked="example===example" and even though it returns true, the radio button remains unchecked.
If I check the Vue console, under props, I can see that checked is true.
So far I tried almost everything I could find around here, without any luck.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Here's the code.

```html
<b-form-radio-group v-model="toateMagazineleSelectate">
  <b-form-radio-group v-model="tipMagazinSelectat" id="magazine" name="magazine">
    <b-form-group v-for="(tipMagazin,index2) in magazine" :key="index2" class="magazine" name="magazine">
      <div class="tipMagazin divCheckbox" v-if="tipMagazin.clasificare !== ''">
        <div class="col-md-11 textTipMagazinSelect">
          {{tipMagazin.clasificare}}
          <span :id="'tipMagazin'+index2" v-b-toggle="'collapse-'+ index2" class="divIcon"></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <b-collapse :id="'collapse-'+ index2" class="collapseBox" visible >
        <b-form-radio-group v-model="model.magazine" class="magazine" name="magazine">
          <div v-for="(magazin,index) in tipMagazin.subclasificari" :key="index" class="divMagazine tipMagazin divCheckbox col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-11 textMagazinSelect">
              {{magazin}}
            </div>
            <b-form-radio
              :checked="magazin === model.subclasificare"
              :value="{ subclasificare: magazin, clasificare: tipMagazin.clasificare}"
              class="tipMagazinCheck magazine"
              @change="changeMagazine(tipMagazin.clasificare, magazin)">
            </b-form-radio>
          </div>
        </b-form-radio-group>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-form-group>
  </b-form-radio-group>
</b-form-radio-group>
```

Comment: The code you've pasted is missing closing tags on some of the components.

Comment: Not sure why, when I try to edit the post I see all the closing tags but when I save, the code is trimmed. Here's the version with all tags closed - https://pastebin.com/2ZxA0iyE

Comment: I edited the post to fix it. If you try to edit now you can see how i fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use simpler and more flexible code for this section of your code. I simulate your situation in codepen to find your problem. I believe that you shouldn't use `:checked` and `:value` at the same time in the `b-form-radio`. I share my code with you and maybe it'll help you to understand. I suggest that put your script section in the question.

Note that I'm using a timeout to show the delay between your request and the response.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      selected: "second",
      options: [{
          text: "First",
          value: "first"
        },
        {
          text: "Second",
          value: "second"
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.selected = "first";
    }, 3000);
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1 variant="primary">Toggle Collapse</b-button>
  <b-collapse id="collapse-1" class="mt-2">
    <b-card>
      <b-form-radio-group id="radio-group-2" v-model="selected" name="radio-sub-component">
        <b-form-radio v-for="item in options" :value="item.value">{{item.text}}</b-form-radio>
      </b-form-radio-group>

      <b-button v-b-toggle.collapse-1-inner size="sm">Toggle Inner Collapse</b-button>
      <b-collapse id="collapse-1-inner" class="mt-2">
        <b-card>
          <b-form-radio-group id="radio-group-1" v-model="selected" :options="options" name="radio-options"></b-form-radio-group>
        </b-card>
      </b-collapse>
    </b-card>
  </b-collapse>
</div>
```